# select all from table where datetime Greater than Timestamp? from C# to mysql

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0

Ok here is my C# code  snippet:

**Updated** is the *time-stamp* column of the table in mysql.

**hair** is a *datetime* variable which I format into the correct format

```
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(
                "SELECT *"
                + "FROM smartstyle.table_changes_logger"
                + "WHERE  Updated = @logout_datetime ;", connection);
            command.Parameters.Add("@logout_datetime",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Timestamp).Value = hair.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            connection.Open();
```

but I am getting the following error why?

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '2013-08-06 02:12:09 '' at line 1"    string

Comment: For starters, you are missing spaces between `*` and `FROM` and between `...logger` and `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't put spaces between `*` and `FROM` and between `...logger` and `WHERE`. Fix like this:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(
            "SELECT * "
            + "FROM smartstyle.table_changes_logger "
            + "WHERE  Updated = @logout_datetime ;", connection);
```

I'd also lose the `;` in the end by the way.